# Filling Missing Dates for a combination of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 3 columns One Date, 2 Object Columns. I need to fill missing dates of different col1 and col 2 combinations by using max and min dates of the dataframe. Date column only contains first day of each month.

I have done it using naive manner but original data is in thousands or records taking huge amount of time to iterate thru all COL1+COL2 combinations, date ranges. original dataframe contains 15000 records and 30 columns. I need to fill missing date + col1 + col2 then rest all columns empty values. If I have data for Jan 2019 for a col1+col2 combination and dont have it for feb I actually wanted to insert feb, col1, col2, other records empty.

**There should be equal unique combinations (COL1 + COL2) from original dataframe  to after filling. Same number of combinations before and after**

Please help me optimizing it.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01','2018-05-01','2018-05-01'],
          'COL1':['A','A','B','B','A'],
          'COL2':['1','2','1','2','1']})
df_1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['Date'])



Initial Dataframe -->> 
         Date COL1 COL2
0 2018-01-01    A    1
1 2018-02-01    A    2
2 2018-03-01    B    1
3 2018-05-01    B    2
4 2018-05-01    A    1
```

--

```
print(df_1.dtypes)

print(df_1)

COLS_COMBO = [i for i in list(set(list(df_1[['COL1','COL2']].itertuples(name='',index=False))))]
months_range = [str(i.date()) for i in list(pd.date_range(start=min(df_1['Date']).date(), 
                   end=max(df_1['Date']).date(), freq='MS'))]

print(COLS_COMBO)

print(months_range)

for col in COLS_COMBO:
    col1,col2 = col[0], col[1]
    for month in months_range:
        d = df_1[(df_1['Date'] == month) & (df_1['COL1'] == col1) & (df_1['COL2'] == col2)]
        if len(d) == 0:
            dx = {'Date':month,'COL1':col1,'COL2':col2}
            df_1 = df_1.append(dx, ignore_index=True)

print(df_1)
```

### OUTPUT

```
Data TYPES -->> 


Date    datetime64[ns]
COL1            object
COL2            object
dtype: object


Unique COmbinations of COL1 + COL2 -->> 
 [('A', '2'), ('B', '2'), ('B', '1'), ('A', '1')]

Months range using min, max in the dataframe -->> 
 ['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01', '2018-05-01']
```

My final output is

```
FINAL Dataframe -->> 

          Date COL1 COL2
0  2018-01-01    A    1
1  2018-02-01    A    2
2  2018-03-01    B    1
3  2018-05-01    B    2
4  2018-05-01    A    1
5  2018-01-01    A    2
6  2018-02-01    A    2
7  2018-03-01    A    2
8  2018-04-01    A    2
9  2018-05-01    A    2
10 2018-01-01    B    2
11 2018-02-01    B    2
12 2018-03-01    B    2
13 2018-04-01    B    2
14 2018-05-01    B    2
15 2018-01-01    B    1
16 2018-02-01    B    1
17 2018-03-01    B    1
18 2018-04-01    B    1
19 2018-05-01    B    1
20 2018-01-01    A    1
21 2018-02-01    A    1
22 2018-03-01    A    1
23 2018-04-01    A    1
24 2018-05-01    A    1
```

PS:

COL1 is like parent COL2 is child. So there should be no change in the original combinations and also (date+col1+col2) combinations shouldn't be duplicated / updated if exists.

Comment: Are there supposed to be duplicates: index 0 and index 20?

Comment: no duplicates. only one combination of month/date+col1+col2. Thanks

Comment: @Chris I dont know how that came here. Didn't I searched for the combinations?? OOPS I have not filtering date with date i think it's string.

Comment: @niteeshk can you tell me in your actual df, how many unique values for COL1? How many unique values for COL2 and how many months does the Date field cover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
from  itertools import product

#get all unique combinations of columns
COLS_COMBO = df_1[['COL1','COL2']].drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
#remove times and create MS date range
dates = df_1['Date'].dt.floor('d')
months_range = pd.date_range(dates.min(), dates.max(), freq='MS')
print(COLS_COMBO)
print(months_range)
```

---

```
#create all combinations of values
df = pd.DataFrame([(c, a, b) for (a, b), c in product(COLS_COMBO, months_range)], 
                   columns=['Date','COL1','COL2'])
print (df)
         Date COL1 COL2
0  2018-01-01    A    1
1  2018-02-01    A    1
2  2018-03-01    A    1
3  2018-04-01    A    1
4  2018-05-01    A    1
5  2018-01-01    A    2
6  2018-02-01    A    2
7  2018-03-01    A    2
8  2018-04-01    A    2
9  2018-05-01    A    2
10 2018-01-01    B    1
11 2018-02-01    B    1
12 2018-03-01    B    1
13 2018-04-01    B    1
14 2018-05-01    B    1
15 2018-01-01    B    2
16 2018-02-01    B    2
17 2018-03-01    B    2
18 2018-04-01    B    2
19 2018-05-01    B    2
```

---

```
#add to original df_1 and remove duplicates
df_1 = pd.concat([df_1, df], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
print (df_1)
         Date COL1 COL2
0  2018-01-01    A    1
1  2018-02-01    A    2
2  2018-03-01    B    1
3  2018-05-01    B    2
4  2018-05-01    A    1
6  2018-02-01    A    1
7  2018-03-01    A    1
8  2018-04-01    A    1
10 2018-01-01    A    2
12 2018-03-01    A    2
13 2018-04-01    A    2
14 2018-05-01    A    2
15 2018-01-01    B    1
16 2018-02-01    B    1
18 2018-04-01    B    1
19 2018-05-01    B    1
20 2018-01-01    B    2
21 2018-02-01    B    2
22 2018-03-01    B    2
23 2018-04-01    B    2
```